# Delimit string by whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

What would be the appropriate regex to delimit a string by all whitespaces? There can also be more than one whitespace between two token and it should ignore whitespaces at the end.

What I have so far:

```
<?php
$tags = "unread dev     test1   ";
$tagsArr = preg_split("/ +/", $tags);
foreach ($tagsArr as $value) {
  echo $value . ";";
}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
"unread;dev;test1;;"
```

As you can see it doesn't ignore the whitespaces at the end because the correct output should be:

```
"unread;dev;test1;"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ignore empty entries using the flag [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](http://php.net/preg_split#refsect1-function.preg-split-parameters):

```
$tagsArr = preg_split("/ +/", $tags, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/1hrNJ

Answer (score 6):

Just use the [trim function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) first to cut away the white space at the end.

$trimmed_tags = trim($tags);

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way:

```
$tagsArr = array_filter( explode(' ', $tags) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you wish to retain white space throughout the string, but remove from the end (to prevent this last annoying semi colon. If I have understood correctly so far, this sounds like the perfect use for the trim command:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php